# CMD: Take file path from user and execute desired command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to create a bat file which take full path of a dll from user and execute regsvr32 command but I couldn't do it somehow. This is what I tried:

```
@echo off
set /p id="Paste full path of the DLL and hit enter"
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k REGSVR32 %id%

PAUSE
```

Note:

Example of command:

```
REGSVR32 /u C:\Windows\System32\cabview.dll
```

Comment: What do you get when you `echo %id%`?

Comment: I get the path that pasted.There is no such a wrong thing about that.

Comment: Does it contain space or special characters?

Comment: Plus, your command in the batch file **does not** match the command you want. Note the `/u` flag

Comment: Open up a command prompt, `cd` to your batch file, execute it by typing `name.bat` from cmd, the error would show up

Comment: `regsvr32.exe` shouldn't need `cmd.exe`, it should work independently, `regsvr32 [-u|-s] "%id%"`

Comment: If you really want to see what is happening, comment out or delete the `@echo off` line.

Comment: @Compo You're correct - `regsvr32` doesn't require an additional `cmd` instance, but just a lot of batch scripters like randomly calling another `cmd` for executing 1 command.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors that Compo and I noticed in your code.

---

First off:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k REGSVR32 %id%
```

is kinda weird. So you are calling `cmd` to execute another `cmd` command, why wouldn't you just do `REGSVR32 %id%`. A lot of new batch scripters go crazy with starting another `cmd` instance.

Then:

```
REGSVR32 %id%
```

If `%ID%` contains special character or space, **it will NEVER work! Even when `echo %ID%` works!!!** We need to use quotes(`"`) to warp up the path/ or the `%id%` like so.

```
RESVR32 "%id%"
```

Finally:

Your batch file command **does not** match the example output! You missed the `/u` flag

---

These are very simple errors, I wish you have debugged the script before asking in Stack Overflow, these sorts of questions will be closed.